# libgdx - I can't see my object rendering

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine, desktop, game-physics

I am new to libgdx. I want to render a ball on the screen, but all I can see is an empty black screen.

**Main**

```
public class Main implements ApplicationListener
{
   @Override
   public void render()
   {
    if (!paused)
    {
        worldController.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0x255/255f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    worldRenderer.render();
   }
}
```

**WorldRenderer**

```
public class WorldRenderer implements Disposable
{
   public void render()
   {
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
      batch.begin();

    for (Ball b : getWorldController().balls)
        b.render(batch);

    batch.end();
   }
}
```

**Ball**

```
public class Ball extends AbstractGameObject
{
    private TextureRegion textureRegion;

    public Ball()
    {
        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/ball.png"));

        dimension.x = 1;
        dimension.y = 1;

        // Center image on game object
        origin.set(dimension.x / 2, dimension.y / 2);
        // Bounding box for collision detection
        bounds.set(0, 0, dimension.x, dimension.y);
        // Set physics values
        terminalVelocity.set(3f, 4f);
        friction.set(12f, 0f);
        acceleration.set(0f, -25f);

        position.x = 5;
        position.y = 5;

        textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, dimension.x, dimension.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        batch.draw( textureRegion,
                    position.x,
                    position.y,
                    origin.x,
                    origin.y,
                    dimension.x,
                    dimension.y,
                    scale.x,
                    scale.y,
                    rotation,
                    false);
    }

}
```

**Abstract game object**:

```
public abstract class AbstractGameObject
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 dimension;
    public Vector2 origin;
    public Vector2 scale;
    public float rotation;

    public Vector2 velocity;
    public Vector2 terminalVelocity;
    public Vector2 friction;
    public Vector2 acceleration;
    public Rectangle bounds;

    public AbstractGameObject()
    {
        this.position = new Vector2();
        this.dimension = new Vector2();
        this.origin = new Vector2();
        this.scale = new Vector2();

        this.velocity = new Vector2();
        this.terminalVelocity = new Vector2();
        this.friction = new Vector2();
        this.acceleration = new Vector2();
        this.bounds = new Rectangle();
    }

    public void updateMotionX(float deltaTime)
    {
        if (velocity.x != 0)
        {
            // Apply friction
            if (velocity.x > 0)
            {
                velocity.x = Math.max(velocity.x - friction.x * deltaTime, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                velocity.x = Math.min(velocity.x + friction.x * deltaTime, 0);
            }
        }

        // Apply acceleration
        velocity.x += acceleration.x * deltaTime;

        // Make sure that acceleration does not exceed the terminal velocity
        velocity.x = MathUtils.clamp(velocity.x, -terminalVelocity.x, terminalVelocity.x);
    }

    public void updateMotionY(float deltaTime)
    {
        if (velocity.y != 0)
        {
            if (velocity.y > 0)
            {
                velocity.y = Math.max(velocity.y - friction.y * deltaTime, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                velocity.y  = Math.min(velocity.y + friction.y * deltaTime, 0);
            }
        }

        // Apply acceleration
        velocity.y += acceleration.y * deltaTime;

        // Make sure that acceleration does not exceed the terminal velocity
        velocity.y = MathUtils.clamp(velocity.y, -terminalVelocity.y, terminalVelocity.y);
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime)
    {
        updateMotionX(deltaTime);
        updateMotionY(deltaTime);

        position.x += velocity.x * deltaTime;
        position.y += velocity.y * deltaTime;
    }

    public abstract void render (SpriteBatch batch);
}
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, you are missing some of your code. Where is your camera code?

Comment: YOu definitly need to show us your camera. Otherwise we can't help. Just a little point: IF you create a camera using `new OrthographicCamera(80, 45)` it will create a new camera, with its 0,0 point in the MIDDLE of the screen, and 80 units in the width and 45 in the height. So your `Ball`s radius would be 1/80 screen width. On a 1600*900 screen (to have beautifull numbers) it would have a radius of 20 px.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your camera, usually in an override of the screen resize:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    this.camera.position.set(width / 2f, height / 2f, 0);
    this.camera.update();
}
```

This will set 1 pixel as 1 unit, so you might want to increase the dimensions of your ball. The bottom left of the screen will be 0,0. I'd also recommend placing your ball in the middle of the screen.